# How to remove space between logos in navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I have a menu where I have some links and logos. You can see that below.

[image: nav menu]

I want 03 logos to close each other. You can see spaces between logos. I don't want to much space between logos.How Can I just remove gap/space between these logos. Help me out.

My HTML Code:

```
  <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl absolute-nav transparent-nav cp-nav navbar-light bg-light fluid-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
          <img src="{% static 'images/logo-2.png'%}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto main-nav">
            <li class="menu-item active"><a title="Home" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a  href="{% url 'jobs' %}">Jobs</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a  href="javascript:void(0)">Career Advice</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a  href="javascript:void(0)">Skill Check</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a  href="javascript:void(0)">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i> <img src="{% static 'images/social-icon/facebook.png'%}" style="height:20px;position: relative;padding: 0;" class="img-fluid" alt=""></i>  </a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i> <img src="{% static 'images/social-icon/linkedIn.png'%}" style="height:20px;position: relative;padding: 0;" class="img-fluid" alt=""></i>  </a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><i> <img src="{% static 'images/social-icon/twitter.png'%}" style="height:20px;position: relative;padding: 0;" class="img-fluid" alt=""></i>  </a></li>
            <li class="menu-item login-popup" id="sign-in"><a href="{% url 'sign-in' %}">Login</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item login-popup" id="register"><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Registration</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="sign-out"><a href="professional/sign-out/">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

MY CSS:

```
.cp-nav-2 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .menu-item {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: #6f7484;
}

.cp-nav-2 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .menu-item a:hover {
  color: #246df8;
}

.cp-nav-2 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .menu-item.post-job {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.cp-nav-2 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .menu-item.post-job a {
  background: #246df8;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 11px 20px;
}

.cp-nav-2 .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .menu-item.post-job a i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you please add css also here ?

Comment: (especially the CSS for the menu-item class)

Comment: I Just Added CSS. Now Should make sense I guess :(

Answer (score 1):

True to the prior. You either use inline CSS like

```css
style="height:20px;position: relative;padding: 0;"
```

or you add a CSS class.

An easy fix in terms of CSS either inline or scripted could be to adjust the position from one item to the next one with something like this line below:

```css
position:relative;right:-6px;
```

You have to play with the pixels to adjust as needed.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is all over the place, i would delete all the classes from your HTML and delete all your css and start again, to get you started if you go off this

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
li {
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

in your css add a class `class="img-fluid"` and then you can just change the properties from there, you don't need to do `style="height:20px;position: relative;padding: 0;"` in your HTML as it will start to get very messy, just do your css in your style.css file

Comment: I also thought to make another class and change css to it. But I have no prior knowledge In CSS. So it is making me sick.

Comment: I just added css. Can you please check :)